# How to configure an index.d.ts file inside the lib folder in SvelteKit

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I have the following directory structure in SvelteKit:

```
...
lib/
   form/
       Input.svelte
       Button.svelte
...
```

I wanted to put an index.d.ts file or something similar so I could import the `index` file instead of each component separately.
Example:

```js
// Instead of using this
import Input from "$lib/form/Input.svelte";
import Button from "$lib/form/Button.svelte";
// I would have an index file inside the folder doing the default export
import { Input, Button } from "$lib/form";
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this by following these steps:

- create any `.ts` file (for example: `index.ts`) in the form folder with the following content:

```
import Button from './button.svelte';
import Input from './input.svelte';
export { Button };
export { Input };
```

- then you can import them like this:

```
import { Input, Button } from "./form/index";
```